# How does vmmap find the name of the library matching a segment in macosx?

Tags: c, macos, memory

Does any one know how vmmap find the library name besides the address and length of the segments for which the segment was allocated ?

Thanks a lot

For example:

```
==== Non-writable regions for process 1115
__TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100099000 [  612K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /bin/bash
__LINKEDIT             00000001000a7000-00000001000b5000 [   56K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /bin/bash
MALLOC guard page      00000001000b5000-00000001000b6000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
MALLOC guard page      00000001000b7000-00000001000b9000 [    8K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
MALLOC guard page      00000001000ce000-00000001000d0000 [    8K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
MALLOC guard page      00000001000e5000-00000001000e6000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
MALLOC metadata        00000001000e6000-00000001000e7000 [    4K] r--/rwx SM=COW  
VM_ALLOCATE            00000001000e7000-00000001000e8000 [    4K] r--/rw- SM=ALI  
STACK GUARD            00007fff5bc00000-00007fff5f400000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack     guard for thread 0
__TEXT                 00007fff5fc00000-00007fff5fc3c000 [  240K] r-x/rwx SM=COW          /usr/lib/dyld
__LINKEDIT             00007fff5fc7b000-00007fff5fc8f000 [   80K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
__TEXT                 00007fff83cde000-00007fff83d1e000 [  256K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
__TEXT                 00007fff84167000-00007fff84260000 [  996K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
__TEXT                 00007fff84970000-00007fff84975000 [   20K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
__TEXT                 00007fff86c34000-00007fff86df6000 [ 1800K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
__LINKEDIT             00007fff893de000-00007fff8b347000 [ 31.4M] r--/r-- SM=COW  /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
```

Comment: It seems /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework is reponsible for the job. http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?StackTraces Seems to contains some information on how to use it ( Symbolication.framework ships withoud headers, though otool -L provides interesting symbol names)

Comment: Just go through the headerfiles inside the /usr/include/sys folder you have a lot of files related to vmmemory mapping. Probably it might help u out. You have files like proc_info.h which has functions for getting process info. Similarly you have vm.h and vmmeter.h for accessing the virtual memory. Hope that helps.